# uploadify not uploading in switch / if - else statement

Tags: php, jquery

I've been using Uploadify plugin to upload files.
Basically, I need to upload different type of documents (photo, floorplan, brochure)

so, below is my uploadify code (the upload form)

```
<? $sid = session_id();  ?>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify214/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'uploader.php?pid=<? echo $pid; ?>&type=<? echo $type; ?>',
        'scriptData': {'session': '<? echo $sid; ?>'},
        'multi': true, // enable multiple upload
        'queueSizeLimit': 5, // number of file at once
        'onQueueFull': function(event, queueSizeLimit) {
            alert("You can only upload " + queueSizeLimit + " files at once");
            return false;
        },
        'cancelImg' : 'js/uploadify214/cancel.png',
        'auto'      : false,
        'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
              window.location = "files.php?pid=<? echo $pid; ?>" // redirect to previous page
        }
    });
});
```

All the upload will be handled by **uploader.php**
and below is the code

```
session_id($_REQUEST['session']);
require_once('function.php');

$pid = $_REQUEST['pid'];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$photo_file = $_FILES['Filedata'];
$photo_tags = 'test';
$status = '1';
$inuse = 0;

// the function will run if i put it here
property_photo_upload($user_id, $pid, $photo_file, $photo_tags, $inuse, 'photo');

// but if i put it in switch / if-else statement, the code will not run
switch($type){
    case 'photo' :
        property_photo_upload($user_id, $pid, $photo_file, $photo_tags, $inuse, 'photo');
        break;

    case 'floorplan' :
        property_doc_upload($user_id, $pid, $photo_file, $photo_tags, $inuse, 'floorplan');
        break;

    case 'brochure' :
        property_doc_upload($user_id, $pid, $photo_file, $photo_tags, $inuse, 'brochure');
        break;
}
```

So, the problem is if i put the upload function OUTSIDE / WITHOUT the switch / if-else statement, the upload progress can run without any problem.
But when i put the function within switch / if-else statement, suddenly the upload is not working.

I need the switch statement so that my code can handle the upload for different file type.

Any help is very appreciated.
sorry for my bad english and long question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check Firebug (or similar) and verify that a value is being set to the `type` query parameter? It may also be useful to add a `default` case to the switch.

Comment: @TiesonT. thanks for reminding me about the default case.
I've checked the javascript using firebug script console, and seems like the $type got the correct parameter.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to not just use the value of `$type`? After running it through `filter_var` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), of course

Comment: I already used different name to replace $type. the result is still the same :(

Comment: What I meant was, use `property_photo_upload($user_id, $pid, $photo_file, $photo_tags, $inuse, $type);`, since your cases match the value you're hard-coding.

Comment: not working either. 
unless i put property_photo_upload($user_id, $pid, $photo_file, $photo_tags, $inuse, 'photo');
i think there is really something wrong with the value $type

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14110/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-s3polz)

Answer (score 0):

main reason is that the variable of $type.

what type of $type ?

call the function of var_dump

Comment: $type is passed from previous page (photo, floorplan, brochure).
I've echo the $type just before the uploadify javascript and the output is correct.
I did check using Firebug javascript console and the value for type is also correct.